# why getting 400 error in console.log after email exists

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, axios, mern

my problem is I am getting 400 error in console . I don't even write console.log() statement in either API or react . is there any solution or should go with this . I am new to this `MERN` . I am a student.
Should I go with this .

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/model")
const bycrypt = require("bcryptjs")

router.post("/sign-up", async (req,res)=>{
    const {username,email,password} = req.body;
    if(!username || !email || !password){
        return res.status(400).json({message:"Please fill all the fields"});
    }
    try{
    const emailExists = await User.findOne({email});
    if(emailExists){
        return res.status(400).json({message:"User already exists"});
    }
    const salt = 10;
    const hashedPassword = await bycrypt.hash(password,salt);
    const newUser = await new User({
        username,
        email,
        password:hashedPassword
    });
     await newUser.save();
     return res.status(201).json({message:"User created successfully"});
    }
    catch(err){
        return res.status(406).json({message:err.message});
    }
});
router.post("/sign-in", async (req,res)=>{
    const {emil,username} = req.body;
    if(!emil || !username){
        return res.status(400).json({message:"Please fill all the fields"});
    }
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({email});
        if(!user){
            return res.status(400).json({message:"Invalaid credentials"});
        }
        const isMatch = await bycrypt.compare(username,user.username);
        if(!isMatch){
            return res.status(400).json({message:"Invalaid credentials"});
        }
        const token = jwt.sign({id:user._id},"jwefvuifyguyffwdjddctdvvfugwtr");
        const {password:hp,...rest}=user._doc;
        res.cookie("access_token",token,{httpOnly:true,expires: new Date(Date.now() + 24 *60*60^1000),path:"/",domain:"www.localhost:5173/"})
    } catch (error) {
        
    }
})

module.exports = router;


import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const App = () => {
  const [input,setInput] = React.useState({
    email:"",
    password:""
  });
  const handleOnchange = (event) =>{
    setInput({
      ...input,[event.target.name]:event.target.value
    })
  }
  const handleSubmit = async (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault();  
  }
  const cl = async () =>{

      const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/log-in",input,{withCredentials:true})
      // if(!response.ok){
      //   console.log("error");
      }
  return (
    <>
    <form method='POST' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="emil" value={input.email} onChange={handleOnchange}/>

      <label htmlFor='password'>Password</label>
      <input type="text" name="password" id="password" value={input.password} onChange={handleOnchange}/>
      <button type="submit" onClick={cl}>Submit</button>
    </form>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

`

I handled 400 error using if statement but now I am getting error in span and in console.
I don't want error in console

Comment: On submit button click you're making a request to `api/log-in`. In your server I don't see this route but `api/sign-in`. Is it something different?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `res.json({status:400,message:"User is already present"});`

and in react you can use

```
if(response.data.status == 400){
setError(response.data.message)}
```